# Check if input is either digits or period

Tags: python

I'm trying to take user input that is separated by a comma and create a list from the entered data. For example, the user inputs `1,2,3,4,5.6,7` and I build a list `[1,2,3,4,5.6,7]`. I also want to make sure that there will not be any letters, but allow spaces, single dots, and numbers. If the user inputs `1,2,3,4.4.3,a`, for example, it should  return a blank `[]` list.

So far I have created

```
def is_numeric(s):
    if s == :
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")

def main():
    s = input("Enter a set of numbers (integers or floats) separated by comman:")
    is_numeric(s)

main()
```

I'm stuck on how I can check if entered numbers would meet these requirements.

Thanks for any help!

By the way, this was a problem I received from a teacher who was giving out practice problems before a quiz but I cannot figure out and he will go over the problems the same day of the quiz which is really too late for me to learn it. This isn't for a grade.

Comment: Do you know about `try` and `except`?  Here I would `try` to convert the strings to `float` and then handle the error if it fails.

Comment: unfortunately i have not learned about try or except... :( my teacher gave a hint that for multi dots you could use the split() method, ex 4.5.6

Comment: @mgilson: But `float` isn't going to work on spaces or single dots.

Comment: thats what i was thinking.... would utilizing ascii.digits and ascii.lowercase be of any benefit in this problem?

Comment: @abarnert -- True.  But I don't think OP wants to allow the strings `"."` or `" "` (though maybe I'm reading between the lines).

Comment: @user2840144: Well, `ascii_lowercase` isn't going to help. But `ascii_digits + ' .'` might.

Comment: @user2840144 -- Do you want to accept negative numbers as well?

Comment: well i want to be able to take . if there is only one between two digits. like 4.5 is ok but 3.5.6 would be wrong because that is not a number.

Comment: @user2840144: Meanwhile, why don't you write the other parts of the code before and after the `is_numeric` part? You can always just make a dummy function that returns `True` for now so you can test the rest. Because you still have to figure out how to split the line on commas, how to call `is_numeric` on all of the split-out values and return `[]` if any of them are false, how to convert them from strings to numbers, etc.

Comment: He didnt specify if negative numbers were needed so i assumed not

Comment: @user2840144 Hint: How many arguments does `str.split` take?

Comment: it is only one argument

Comment: @user2840144 `str.split()` takes a second, optional argument. What does it do?

Comment: would it be a numeric value that sets the max split count?

Comment: @user2840144: So, if you have the part between two commas, and you write `part.split('.', 1)`, what does that tell you?

Comment: this would split each inputed "number" to be its own object right? as in 1.2.5 would break up to 1 2 5?

Comment: using split('.', 1) would i be looking to make sure there is only two objects and not more within the separating comma?

Comment: @user2840144: Yes, it does make sure you only get two objects—but it does more than that; it also gives you an easy way to check if there are too many dots. `"1.25"` will split into `["1", "25"]`, but `"1.2.5"` into `["1", "2.5"]`. So, `.isdigit()` is the only rule you need, for each half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to do this is to walk the string character by character. But if you're teacher suggested splitting on dots, I think he wanted something like this pseudocode:

```
def is_numeric(s):
    remove whitespace before and after the string
    split on the first '.'
    if and only if all of the split-out parts are all digits, return True
```

If you know the `strip`, `split`, `all`, and `isdigit` functions, this should be even shorter and more readable in Python than in pseudocode. The documentation for [Built-In Functions](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) and [String Methods](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) should fill in the gaps if you don't know everything.

Now, to see if the input as a whole is valid, you need to split on commas and check each part, so:

```
parts = s.split(',')
if not all(is_numeric(part) for part in parts):
    result = []
else:
    result = [float(part) for part in parts]
```

If those comprehensions are beyond your knowledge, you can write the same thing more verbosely as:

```
parts = s.split(',')
result = []
for part in parts:
    if not is_numeric(part):
        result = []
        break
    else:
        result.append(float(part))
```

---

Here's the entire thing:

```
def is_numeric(s):
    s = s.strip()
    parts = s.split('.', 1)
    return all(part.isdigit() for part in parts)

def parse_input(line):
    parts = line.split(',')
    if not all(is_numeric(part) for part in parts):
        return []
    else:
        return [float(part) for part in parts]

while True:
    line = input("You will provide numbers. Provide! Provide! ")
    if not line:
        break
    values = parse_input(line)
    print("Reporting provided numbers:", values)
```

And here's a transcript:

```
You will provide numbers. Provide! Provide! 1,2,3,4,5.6,7
Reporting provided numbers: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.6, 7.0]
You will provide numbers. Provide! Provide! 1,2,3,4.4.3,a
Reporting provided numbers: []
You will provide numbers. Provide! Provide! 1, 2, 3, 4
Reporting provided numbers: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
You will provide numbers. Provide! Provide! 1.2, 3.4.5
Reporting provided numbers: []
You will provide numbers. Provide! Provide!
```

It's worth testing out some of the expressions in the interactive interpreter to see what they do. And adding some `print` statements in the middle of the code to show you intermediate values, if you're not sure what they are. For example, if you don't know what gets fed to `is_numeric`, have it `print(s)`. If you want to know what `.split('.', 1)` returns for different strings, try it: `'1.2.3'.split('.', 1), '1.2'.split('.', 1), '1'.split('.', 1)`. And so on.

Comment: well the is_numeric is supposed to either return true or false when look for digits, comma, space, or dot in the string s. After that i should be converting the string to a list. i need to convert the string characters to ints assuming there are no dots, and to floats if and only if there is one . between two commas right?

Comment: @user2840144: If you look at the "driver" code in the second half, it's already splitting on commas. So, you don't want `is_numeric` to check for digits, comma, space, or dot; you want it to check for digits, exactly zero or one dots, and extra spaces only before and after the number—in other words, something that's a single valid number.

Comment: @user2840144: Meanwhile, if you get stuck translating the pseudocode to Python, I can write it for you, but see how far you can get first.

Comment: for removing the whitespaces, i used this, s.replace(" ", ""), for splitting the first '.' i am unsure to do, and for the all of the split out parts, that would be where i use something like if i.isdigit(): return true, else false?

Comment: @user2840144: `s.replace(" ", "")` will remove _all_ spaces. Do you want `"5 . 6"` to be a valid number, or just things like `" 5.6"`? For the latter, see the `strip` method.

Comment: @user2840144: For splitting the first `.`, that's exactly what kojiro was explaining to you in the comments: `s.split('.', 1)`. (I would personally use `partition` rather than `split` here, because it avoids having to worry about whether you get back 1 value or 2, but it's not that hard either way.)

Comment: i dont believe having "5 . 6" should be a vaild number.

Comment: would you be able to build the code fully so i could see how you setup all of the definition statements to run the program?

Comment: @user2840144: If `"5 . 6"` shouldn't be a valid number, you don't want `s.replace(" ", "")`. Anyway, I'll edit it to show the full code.

Comment: thanks so much! you have been the best help on stackoverflow for me yet :). your structure makes a lot of sense, and i followed each step using the debugger so it made sense easist. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve this with regex.

```
# make sure the input is valid (probably a better way than sub) 
if input == ':)' or re.sub('^[\d\.,]+$', ':)', input) != ':)':
   return []

# get all the comma separated values and convert it to an array of floats
return [float(num) for num in re.findall('([\d\.]+),?', input)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the submission, i havent learned about regex yet, but is this checking the entire string for invalid characters here? if re.sub('^[\d\.,]+$', ':)', input) != ':)':

Comment: @user2840144 Yes. However, if the input is ':)' that's another story. Lets me update my answer to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd normalize the input so I know what to expect. Spaces are slightly easier to deal with than commas, so separate everything by a space.

```
inpt.replace(',', ' ')
```

Now input is something like `'2 3 4.5   6'` with some nonzero number of spaces between each value to be parsed. `split` can deal with that nicely.

```
inlist = inpt.split()
```

Now we have a list, and we just need to know if we need to throw it away.

```
if all([is_numeric(i) for i in inlist]):
  return [int(i, 10) if i.isdigit() else float(i) for i in inlist]
else:
  return []
```

So, what is `is_numeric`? It's a function that, given an element, determines if it is an `int` or a `float` or not. If it's not one of those, we toss it. mgilson suggested something like

```
def is_numeric(i):
  try:
    float(i)
    return True
  except ValueError:
    pass
  return False
```

which would be great, but if you don't want to do try/except, you can still use the second argument to `split` your teacher suggested.

```
def is_numeric(i):
  parts = i.split('.', 1)
  if len(parts) == 2:
    characteristic, mantissa = parts # I really just wanted an excuse to use these terms
    if '.' in mantissa:
      return False
    return True
  elif i.isdigit():
    return True
  return False
```

Comment: haha the mantissa part gave me a chuckle! so basically the try and except test if the number is indeed a float and if there is a value error it returns false?

Comment: @user2840144 yes, open a terminal and try casting a few different strings to `float` to see what happens. You hopefully will also see why I'm careful to cast *some* values to `int`, not `float`.